# Widget stuck at particular point when dragging to bottom

Tags: widgets, wp-admin, drag-drop

This is weird, but when I try to drag a widget to the bottom of sidebar it stuck in the middle, if I hold the dragging and drag it back to top it works but I can't drag it bellow that particular point.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**

I recorded a video of what's going on, here it is: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/coh3YXf6sl
Also, I didn't tell before, I am using Jetpack plugin for widgets visibility on certain pages etc.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in multiple browsers or platforms?

Comment: checked on Mac/Safari, still same issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug of WordPress core: [#32094](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32094)

Will be fixed in 4.2.3 version of WordPress and patch is available here: [32094.patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/32094/32094.patch)